# Are there new shortcut keys in recent update (04-2019)?

Tags: shortcut-keys

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> takes me to lock screen. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> takes me to a terminal outside of window manager.

Is this something that was introduced in a recent Ubuntu update, or is it just my system? These shortcuts do not appear in the keyboard settings.

edit: Using gnome, Ubuntu 18.04.2

edit2: After a reboot, everything is back to normal.

Comment: Which desktop environment is this? And what do you mean by "takes me to a terminal outside of window manager"?

Comment: Probably OP refer to TTY by "takes me to a terminal outside of window manager".

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I don't see any of what you're seeing on Ubuntu 19.04 (X.Org).

Comment: I have the same (new) behaviour on 18.04.2 since the latest update today: Pressing Alt+Right and Alt+Left lets me cycle through the TTYs (including the two graphical ones). I haven't rebooted yet and cannot tell if it vanishes then.

Comment: @PerlDuck but yours aren't the keyboard shortcuts OP describes.

Comment: @DKBose Oh, yes, you are right. But the keys the OP describes also show the new behaviour on my PC, i.e. Alt+Right and Alt+Tab+Right both switch _one TTY to the right_.

Comment: @PerlDuck [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/520546) could be related with `sudo kbd_mode -s` as [a workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/be4x1w/meta_left_arrow_drops_into_virtual_console_why/el3zw7c?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).